# How do you move two images to the left and right in a div element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, position

I am using HTML, and I am trying to make a part of a webpage where I have a textbox in the center of the screen and five images surrounding the textbox.

I am able to place three images above the box, but when I try to place an image to the left and to the right of the textbox, the images seem to be "stuck" in the center of the page. All this is in a div element.

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: This is why CSS grid frameworks exist.

Comment: try css float:right and float:left

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do this is with grid system. In example if you use [Bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) you can do it like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"><img src="source" alt="something" ></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">Textbox</div>
  <div class="col-md-4"><img src="source" alt="something" ></div>
</div>
```

You can also do it without grid system like Gerasimos answer.

Comment: You can improve your answer by adding a link of Bootstrap grid guide... :)

Comment: You get an upvote from me for the link of bootstrap and for improving your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [CSS position property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) if this doesn't work try entering this code in your style sheet:

```
#left-image { position: absolute; left: 10px}
#right-image { position: absolute; right: 10px}
```

Comment: Hi Ethan, from my experience I learned that position property should be rarely used and only when it is really needed. Else, later you might have issues on designing your existing content or adding more...